# flip board menu style for android

Tags: java, android, flipboard

In my app,first activity if we click one button it should open sencond activity with transparence only at the end some part. So when we are in second activity, the content of first activity should visible some part. Its like exactly Flipboard  style menu in android, in flip board if we click top red button we will get another screen in that we can visible previous screen at the bottom like this i need. If any one having ideas please share with me how to do flip board style menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) for this problem that's what they are made for.

If you want to use API 8, I still recomment Fragments but then you need to use [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) it provides you with all features you need.

Comment: thank u for ur info, but my app should work from api level 8, fragments requires api level 11

Comment: Thank you for your time, am trying in this way, i will get back to you